# local variable 'moodsc' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

In the code below I get the following error:

"local variable 'moodsc' referenced before assignment"

I'm new to programming and python. I'm struggling with interpreting other questions on the similar topic.  Any context around this specific code would be helpful.

```
import re
import json
import sys

def moodScore(sent, myTweets):

  scores = {} # initialize an empty dictionary
  new_mdsc = {} # intitalize an empty dictionary
  txt = {}

  for line in sent:
    term, score  = line.split("\t")  # The file is tab-delimited. "\t" means "tab character"
    scores[term] = int(score)  # Convert the score to an integer.

  data = [] # initialize an empty list

  for line in myTweets:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    if "text" in tweet and "lang" in tweet and tweet["lang"] == "en":
      clean = re.compile("\W+")
      clean_txt = clean.sub(" ", tweet["text"]).strip()
      line = clean_txt.lower().split()  

  moodsc = 0
  pos = 0
  neg = 0
  count = 1

  for word in range(0, len(line)):
    if line[word] in scores:
       txt[word] = int(scores[line[word]])
    else: 
       txt[word] = int(0)
    moodsc += txt[word]
    print txt 

    if any(v > 0 for v in txt.values()): 
      pos = 1 
    if any(v < 0 for v in txt.values()): 
      neg = 1 

    for word in range(0, len(line)): # score each word in line
      if line[word] not in scores:
        if str(line[word]) in new_mdsc.keys():
          moodsc2 = new_mdsc[str(line[word])][0] + moodsc
          pos2 = new_mdsc[str(line[word])][1] + pos
          neg2 = new_mdsc[str(line[word])][2] + neg
          count2 = new_mdsc[str(line[word])][3] + count
          new_mdsc[str(line[word])] = [moodsc2, pos2, neg2, count2]
        else:
          new_mdsc[str(line[word])] = [moodsc, pos, neg, count] 

def new_dict():
  for val in new_mdsc.values():
    comp = val[0] / val[3]
    val.append(comp)

  for key, val in new_mdsc.items():
    print (key, val[4])

def main():
    sent_file = open(sys.argv[1])
    tweet_file = open(sys.argv[2])
    moodScore(sent_file, tweet_file)
#    new_dict()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for educating me to provide clarity up front.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "term_sentiment.py", line 75, in <module>
        main()
      File "term_sentiment.py", line 71, in main
        moodScore(sent_file, tweet_file)
      File "term_sentiment.py", line 58, in moodScore
        new_mdsc[str(line[word])] = [moodsc, pos, neg, count] 
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'moodsc' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1):

Ok @joshp, I think you need to globalise some variables, because the error is 'moodsc referenced before assignment', I think the code only gets as far as `moodsc += txt[word]` but you may also have trouble with `pos` and `neg`.

Try `global moodsc` and `pos` etc. before you define `moodsc` and `pos` etc. If this doesn't work try `global moodsc` before `moodsc += txt[word]` and so forth, you may need to use global in both places for it to work, I often find that this is needed in my code, to globalise it at definition and wherever else you use it (at the start of each function and statement where it is used).